# Acumatica REST - CustomerLocation entity does not return records

Tags: rest, acumatica

Using REST API, able to pull down customers, contacts, and addresses via the `Customer` entity, however, when I try to get `CustomerLocation` entities, I am just getting an empty set.

`[]`

Using latest version as of the writing of this question (2018R1 dated something like Aug 17 2018).

I've tried the following:

`CustomerLocation?$expand=LocationContact`

`CustomerLocation?$expand=LocationContact,LocationContact/Address`

Neither of them return any data.

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomerLocation` entity is linked to a Generic Inquiry that is defined to allow creation of new records, so it was causing an error trying to persist the data when trying to do a `Put` to it since I was not supplying a body or a valid structure.

How I got this to work was to create my own Generic Inquiry, linking it to an entity in my extended endpoint, and adding a `Detail` property within the entity that would serve as the collection of detail records returned by the Generic Inquiry.  Then put all of the fields from the Generic Inquiry within the `Results` Fields.

[image: Add Results Property]

[image: Add Generic Inquiry Return fields to Fields inside of Results]

Now, I can get the records from the Generic Inquiry by doing a `Put` request via my endpoint entity:
`AICustomerLocationGI?$expand=Results`

**Note:** It's important to do a `Put` instead of a `Get` if you want to avoid getting BQL Delegate errors on some DACs.

That returned all records at once, but got me where I initially needed to be.  Next, I added a parameter, Greater Than condition, and sorting on Address ID to the Generic Inquiry and defined the generic inquiry to return the top 100 records. By passing the last Address ID of the previous batch of records in the body of the `Put` request, this gave me a paging mechanism for returning the records.